# ClrZmq returning messages always to first started client

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, clr, zeromq, akka-zeromq

We're creating a WPF app in which we execute python scripts from different Test Stations and show the output in its corresponding output panel, To run the scripts in parallel we are using Task but when we run the scripts in parallel from the stations, We are getting the output of other stations also into the station that is started first, we're using the following code,

```
private void ZmqStatusListener(string endPoint)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        StatusPort = string.Empty;
        TestResultPort = string.Empty;
        using (Socket server = context.Socket(SocketType.REP))
        {
            try
            {
                if (isStatusContextActive == false || isPortChanged == true)
                {
                    server.Bind(endPoint);
                    isStatusContextActive = true;
                }
            }
            catch (ZMQ.Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Errno != 100)
                {
                    string IPCPort = _globalParameters.GlbParam.GlbParamIpcStartPort;
                    if (IPCPort == string.Empty)
                    {
                        IPCPort = "0";
                    }
                    if (endPoint == EditorConstants.PortAddress.PortPrefix + IPCPort)
                    {
                        StatusPort = endPoint;
                        TestReultError = EditorConstants.CommonMessageTypes.TestReultError + ex.Message + EditorConstants.CommonMessageTypes.StackTraceMessage + ex.StackTrace;
                    }
                    StopExecOfScript(default(object));
                    isCancelledtask = true;
                    ScriptStatusDesc = new ScriptStatusDesc()
                    {
                        Status = "Failed",
                        statusDescription = "Failed"
                    };
                }
            }
            while (true)
            {
                string message = server.Recv(Encoding.UTF8);
                UpdateTestResults(message);
                server.Send(" ACK", Encoding.UTF8);
                // if (message == "Test Passed")
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and for testing purpose we're breaking the while loop in this code based on a test message we kept in the python script, then we are able to get the output in the respective station correctly but this way we can only run in a synchronous fashion which we don't want as we require to run the test stations in parallel and the while loop should not break as it should be listening for the response.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the issue by getting clues doing a sample app to reproduce the issue and to first know whether our **ClrZmq pattern** was correct for us or not and it is correct. The resolution we followed is that when we needed to bind that data to its corresponding **View's** **Model** object in its **ViewModel** so had to retrieve **View's** **DataContext** which is of Type **ISomeXViewModel** for the particular **TestStation** using an Id of that **TestStation** we did this cos all of our TestStations are dynamically added and we even store it to be accessed wherever necessary. This issue was caused to due multiple instances of UserControls so we explicitly needed to update the **TestStation** manually with a little more effort.

Sample Code Snippet

private void BindTestResult(string xmlPayLoad)

{

// converting xmlPalLoad to a class/model object

ITestStationViewModel viewModel = (ITestStationViewModel)((IView)DynamicTestStationsGrid.Children[StationNumber].Content).DataContext;

// **IView** class has DataContext property so I am type casting the **Content** which is **ContentControl** to **IView** type first and later to **ITestStationViewModel**

viewModel.TestStationModel = xmlPayLoadModel;

}

Thanks.